# Converting string to web-safe Base64 format python 3.x

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk

I am testing how to update user picture using the Admin SDK Directory Service with Python using the following :

```
filename = input('Drag And Drop File\n')
image = open(filename,'rb')
image_read = image.read()
image_encoder = base64.b64encode(image_read)
our_str = image_encoder.decode('utf-8')
new_str = our_str.replace('/', '_').replace('+', '-').replace('=', '*')

def update_photo():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
    #Update Photo
    eventx = {
        "photoData": new_str,
        "mimeType": "JPEG"
        }

    print('Updating photo')
    update_photo = service.users().photos().update(userKey='hidden@hiddendomain.com', body=eventx).execute()
    return update_photo

photo_updated = update_photo()
print (photo_updated)
```

i am getting this error

```
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/hidden@hiddendomain.com/photos/thumbnail?alt=json returned "Invalid value for ByteString: my base64 code
```

reference
(https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/photos/update),

Comment: Try using `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(image_read)` provided by the base64 module instead of inventing your own transformation.

Comment: return json.dumps(body_value)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py", line 192, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py", line 250, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py", line 173, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. [Found this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/w49c2u/how_to_transfer_image_in_to_websafe_base64_format/), changed my code by it and it worked:

```py
with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
    data = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('ascii')

user_photo = {"id": user_id,
            "primaryEmail": email,
            "kind": "admin#directory#user#photo",
            "photoData": data,
            "mimeType": "JPG",
            "width": width,
            "height": height}
results = service.users().photos().update(userKey=email, body=user_photo).execute()
```